# Having problems with integrated Fancybox plugin in eleganttheme's theme in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, fancybox

My wordpress theme comes with integrated Fancybox , you can see it in use here http://bit.ly/xxQ1a8  . This page is created automatically by gallery template, and is hot suitable for my needs.

I am trying to create my own custom picture galley based on Fancybox plugin http://bit.ly/zFLEpR , but for some reason it doesn't work...

Can someone take a peek and see if they can spot what preventing it from working? I spent whole day yesterday trying to figure it out.

Comment: Look into developer tools such as firebug for firefox. A quick peek at firebug's console reveals the problem.

Comment: Can you please specify what the problem is? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice in the source that you're using `$` for the jQuery object, but jQuery has been loaded in no-conflict mode, so the object is called just 'jQuery'. Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("a[rel='group']").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'       :   600, 
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        'overlayShow'   :   false
    });
});
jQuery("a.grouped_elements").fancybox();
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work, I also removed $("a.grouped_elements").fancybox();  , it was left out when I was trying different examples from fancybox's official site.

Comment: I found another error in your code,and updated my answer above to address it. The jQuery selector you are using isn't quite correct.

Comment: You are my hero!!!! I spent entire day yesterday, and all morning trying to make it work. You saved my life!!!!